# Reduce Future sequentially in vert.x

Tags: java, promise, future, vert.x

In my project I am using the `Future` implementation of vert.x in Java. So far everything went fine. However, currently I have problems executing an action on a list of objects sequentially. The problem lies in the `reduce` method "reducing" and "combining" results seperately in Java. This results in all the actions to be started simultaneously. Achieving sequential execution is possible, as one can see in the `easy` method.

```
private Future<Void> action(String object) {
    System.out.println("started " + object);
    Future<Void> f = Future.future();
    vertx.setTimer(1000, res -> {
        System.out.println("doing " + object);
        f.complete();
    });
    return f;
}

private void easy() {
    action("one")
        .compose(ignore -> action("two"))
        .compose(ignore -> action("three"))
        .setHandler(ignore -> System.out.println("completed"));
}

private void list() {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add("one");
    l.add("two");
    l.add("three");

    Future<Void> f = Future.future();
    l.stream().reduce(f,
        (f1, s) -> action(s),
        (f1, f2) -> f2.compose(ignore -> f1)
    ).setHandler(res -> {
        System.out.println("completed");
    });
}
```

Output when executing easy:

```
started one
doing one
started two
doing two
started three
doing three
completed
```

Ouput when executing list:

```
started one
started two
started three
doing one
doing two
doing three
completed
```

The same snippet in Javascript works, as the reduce function does reducing and combining in one step:

```js
function action(object) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("started " + object)
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("doing " + object);
      resolve()
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function easy() {
  action("one")
    .then(() => action("two"))
    .then(() => action("three"))
    .then(() => console.log("completed"));
}

function list() {
  l = ["one", "two", "three"]
  l.reduce((p, s) => p.then(() => action(s)), Promise.resolve())
    .then(() => console.log("completed"));
}

// easy()
list()
```

Output for `easy` and `list` is same as easy method of Java code. What I am looking for, is a way to fix the reduce method in Java or an alternative way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I found an implementation of the a foldLeft method [here](https://gist.github.com/hamnis/d4dcac2345ff57415723) and now sequential execution is working properly...

```
private void list() {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add("one");
    l.add("two");
    l.add("three");

    Future<Void> f = Future.succeededFuture();

    foldLeft(l.iterator(), f,
        (f1, s) -> f1.compose(ignore -> action(s)))
        .setHandler(res -> {
            System.out.println("completed");
        });
}

private static <A, B> B foldLeft(Iterator<A> iterator, B identity, BiFunction<B, A, B> bf) {
    B result = identity;
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        A next = iterator.next();
        result = bf.apply(result, next);
    }
    return result;
}
```